# Modifying callback for Image Upload button

Tags: media

I am trying to access the upload button of an Image field. The field itself is in a field collection.
Using dpm, I can access the field collection, and the image field.

What I want is to create a callback for the upload button such that once the upload is complete, the callback
is triggered (ultimately to call a js function). I have found a few articles on how to do this for custom made, from 
scratch forms, but very little, and nothing yet that seems to work for me on existing, core forms.

I have been racking my brain for a couple of hours looking through elements via dpm, and researching, but I haven't
found any fruitful examples related to this particular use-case.

I also tried tinkering with hook_field_widget_form_alter, which triggers for each element on every load, including
initial load.  I haven't been able to narrow it down to just the one event yet.

I went a completely different way as well, trying to intercept the click on the input via jQuery, which would then
use a timer to check for the uploaded file in the new DOM output, and continue if found, but I cant get the click to
work - I don't know if the built in ajax is over-ruling my code, or just a big conflict is causing it to fail for my own code.

Does anyone have any suggestions or direction on where I should look next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [hook_file_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7) or   [hook_file_insert()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_insert/7) or [hook_file_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_update/7)

Comment: this did work, but I ended up going a different direction anyways...